# Downgrading packages with pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

What is the best, or most suitable, method of **downgrading** packages in *Arch*?

On normal days I just run the following to accomplish a quick downgrade:

```
 # pacman -Rd <broken-package>
 # pacman -U  <older-stable-package-pkg.tar.gz>
```

But today I am downgrading my *kernel*, which is a very vital part of my linux life. I'd like to do it correctly.

Is this the proper way? If not, what is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking unless there is a dep depending on it (in which case leaving it that way would break something), `pacman -U  <older-stable-package-pkg.tar.gz>` will do the job correctly. Also you should avoid `-Rd` when doing things that could break your system unless **You know what you are doing**, because otherwise the system will complain if you're trying to downgrade in a way that will break a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

If you have packages with a newer version (i.e. testing) and you want to downgrade in batch to stable version, you can execute the following pacman commands:

#### Refresh the sync databases:

```
# pacman -Syy
```

#### Downgrade all packages with a lower version in the repos:

```
# pacman -Suu
```

Comment: Presumably, you meant to include a line about removing the [Testing] repos from your `/etc/pacman.conf` first. Otherwise, this will not downgrade anything...

Comment: I don't agree. If you remove the testing repo you will keep your testing packages until it appears new version in the other repos. The way I proposed let you select manually testing packages, and automatically update only normal repos (lower version in the database), furthermore downgrading testing packages if any.

Comment: You misunderstand my comment. `pacman -Syy` force syncs the db against the repos in `pacman.conf` - unless you change `pacman.conf` _nothing_ will be donwgraded. Read `man pacman` for details.

Comment: You've missunderstood the aim of `pacman -Suu`. You don't need to change `pacman.conf`. You _shall_ have more than one version of packages in repos to get `pacman -Suu` working. If you have _only_ one version of every package `pacman -Suu` is useless, of course. `pacman -Suu` downgrades to the lower version of packages in the repos.

Comment: `man pacman: -Su`: "Pass this option twice to enable package downgrade; in this case pacman will select _sync packages_ whose version does not match with the _local version_. This can be useful when the user switches from a testing repo to a stable one." That seems clear to me.

Comment: That's why maybe you should have read the manual first and then tested the commands, instead of presuming.